# Given a ration x:y, make it to ratio of 1:1 or 3:4 or 4:3 by only adding some values to x or y or both.

Tags: ratio

This problem is related to programing, for which I am searching an optimal solution.

Problem: I have some images in different height to width ratios. I want to make them in ratios of 1:1 or 3:4 or 4:3, by adding white space. I want to add as little white space as possible, to make it in any of the 3 given ratio. I never want to reduce.

Currently my solution is to create 3 new images for 3 given ratios and then checking for which the program needed to add the least no. of pixel. I then go with that. However currently I am adding pixel to only one side, which I have found is not good and in some cases adding pixel to both the side reduces total no. of white pixel added.

I also have tried searching google, but I don't know what this problem is called i.e what to search for. Hence I am here seeking an insight from you.

I hope the solution to this problem will be with in the limits of high school Maths as anything beyond it, will make the solution harder to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, that the solution does boil down essentially to creating the three images - or at least their sizes, and test.

If the original is $x\times y$, then the smallest fitting $1:1$ is clearly $$\max\{x,y\}\times\max\{x,y\}.$$

For the smallest fitting $4:3$ ratio, let $x'=\cdot\lceil x/4\rceil$, $y'=\cdot \lceil y/3\rceil$ and take 
$$4\max\{x',y'\}\times 3\max\{x',y'\}.$$

Similarly, for the smallest fitting $3:4$ ratio, let $x'=\cdot\lceil x/3\rceil$, $y'=\cdot \lceil y/4\rceil$ and take 
$$3\max\{x',y'\}\times 4\max\{x',y'\}.$$

Pick the format that leads to the smallest product.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me, is it possible to do something that will result in only integer numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, so you have you given $$\frac{x}{y}=t$$ and you want to have $$\frac{x+\alpha}{y+\beta}=\frac{4}{3}$$
from the last equation we get
$$3x+3\alpha=4y+4\beta$$b with $x=ty$ we obtain
$$y(3t-4)=4\beta-3\alpha$$ so $$y=\frac{4\beta-3\alpha}{3t-4}$$ and $$x=\frac{t(4\beta-3\alpha}{3t-4}$$

Comment: Sir, This is what I am doing, I am getting 2 variables that I need to solve for. I keep one variable constant and solve for other, which is mathematically correct but not optimal. I need to find the smallest possible pair values that I can add to  x and y to get 1:1 or 3:4 or 4:3